# Spring Boot JPA не могу настроить работу с двумя DataSource

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Я на самом деле перерыл все решения, не знаю, что делать.

Цель: настроить работу с двумя источниками данных

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C://new_workspace//Database//db1.db
spring.datasource.username=sa1
spring.datasource.password=sa2
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

datasource.s.url=jdbc:h2:file:C://new_workspace//Database//db2.db
datasource.s.username=sa2
datasource.s.password=sa2
datasource.s.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

1. Создаю @primary Config (не обращайте внимание на название - second, я ставил/переставлял аннотации и т.д.)

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.ds.repsecond")
   public class SecondDataSource {

   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.s")
   @Primary
   @Bean
   public DataSource sDataSource(){
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }  
   }
   ```

Тут все хорошо, создаю CrudRepository:

```
    public interface HobbyRepository extends CrudRepository<NhobbyEntity, Long>         {

}
```

в контроллере он подхватывается, все хорошо.

```
@Autowired
HobbyRepository hobbyRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<NhobbyEntity> getIndex(){
    Iterable<NhobbyEntity> entities = hobbyRepository.findAll();

    return entities;
}
```

Хочу подключить второй, делаю как в официальной документации:

```
@Configuration

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.ds.repfirst"
)
public class FirstDataSource {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource pDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

}

Конфиг не подхватывается (с аннотацией - автоконфиг тоже). Т.е. подключение ко второй БД не идет.


И все репозитории, вроде как описанные как для второй БД подключаются к       первой.
```

Стал смотреть решения дальше, увидел, что все реализуют для второй ДС стандартную связку: DS, EMF, TM

реализовал:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.ds.repfirst"
    ,                     entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManager"
    ,                     transactionManagerRef = "h2tm"
)
public class FirstDataSource {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource pDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name="h2EntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
    return builder.dataSource(pDataSource())
            .packages("ru.ds.entities")
            .build();
}

@Bean (name="h2tm")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

По крайней мере подключается к БД
При старте пишет:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private final java.util.List
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error
>   creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory
>   method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory
>   method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory
>   method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hobbyRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#73fe8e8d' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#73fe8e8d': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory
>   method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory
>   method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory
>   method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hobbyRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#73fe8e8d' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#73fe8e8d': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Думаю, что беда в автоконфигурации, отключаю:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
```

не помогает, продолжает ругаться.

Конфигурирую основной класс полностью сам.  Ничего не работает.

Все ссылки и мануалы перепробовал, ничего не работает.

Может у кого-нибудь есть рабочий gist?

Comment: Вопрос конечно задан давно. Что то мне подсказывает что тут проблема не в том, что не удается подключить вторую базу. По-моему Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is - Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters. Возможно я не прав, но где то один бин инициализуется до того, как создастся бин, используемый в нем.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал вариант с 2 датасорсами по этой доке http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases. Работало. Только в этом случае надо доменные объекты разделять.

Если же надо надо разделять доменные объекты среди всех датасорсов, то у спринга есть https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/
Делал вариант 1 датасорс для записи в одну базу, другой датасорс для чтения из нескольких (в постгресе была включена синхронная репликация). Работало
Примеры искал на гитхабе поиском строки AbstractRoutingDataSource.